# How to navigate through NYT API JSON return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I'm  using jquery to try to navigate through the New York Times api. I'm connecting to the server and getting a JSON response but I'm not able to properly iterate through the JSON object and am getting nothing in my items. 
This is my code:

```
     var url = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=new york&page=1&api-key=9e4043438fa8df45282e8e570e9ac5ed:5:74988126";
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
        items.push("<li> <a href='" + response.docs[0].web_url + "' >" + response.docs[0].abstract + "</a>" + "<p>" + response.docs[0].snippet + "</p>");
    });
     console.log(items);
});
```

Here's a link to the New York Times api guide: http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/read/article_search_api_v2 
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

 Thank you very much in advance for your time, effort, and help.

Comment: what is response here???

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
 $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        data.response.docs.forEach(function(d){
            items.push("<li> <a href='" + d.web_url + "' >" + d.abstract + "</a>" + "<p>" + d.snippet + "</p>");
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

correted code working..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=new york&page=1&api-key=9e4043438fa8df45282e8e570e9ac5ed:5:74988126", function(result){
         var items = [];
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                items.push("<li> <a href='" + result.response.docs[0].web_url + "' >" + result.response.docs[0].abstract + "</a>" + "<p>" + result.response.docs[0].snippet + "</p>");
alert(result.response.docs[0].web_url); 
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```